# jQuery flip animation showing through DIV on top

Tags: jquery, flip

I'm using the jquery flip plugin to flip a div. I have a larger DIV that is atop the DIV that flips. But when the DIV flips the animation shows through the DIV on top. I don't want the DIV that flips to show through the DIV on top. See an example of the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/4dPaX/7/

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While animation the flipbox has `z-index: 9999;`, so raise the `z-index` of the overlay over 9999:

```
.overlay {
    ...
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Also see your updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4dPaX/10/).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the `z-index` property of the flip box to a higher value than the one the overlay div is having.
Here's the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/4dPaX/9/